# Wrap some text in Django Admin field

Tags: python, django, django-admin, textfield

I have this Django admin page: [image]

The second field, "Descrizione", contains a string (taken from a database) of max 500-chars length: **I want that this text is entirely displayed in the page**, while Django sets up a field as long as the string length, and so I have to sshift it with the right arrow in order to read it.

So, how can I make an automatic text wrapping?

Hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: into the models.py file, modify the related field as TextField.